# Unique random integers in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to generate unique (distinct) random numbers in posgresql (and redshift in particular)? The following code generates 5 random integers from 1 to 10 *with* replacement:

```
SELECT round(random()*(10 - 1) + 1) from generate_series(1, 5);
```

Is there a way to generate a set of 5 random integers from 1 to 10 *without* replacement? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `generate_series` to generate all the numbers between 1 and 10, shuffle them in the `order by` clause and then take the top 5:

```
SELECT   num
FROM     GENERATE_SERIES (1, 10) AS s(num)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try These selects

**1.)**

```
 
    SELECT (9 * random())::int + 1 r_num
    FROM   generate_series(1, 10)
    GROUP  BY 1
    LIMIT  5;
```

**2.)**

```
     
    SELECT round(random()*(10 - 1) + 1)::int r_num
    FROM   generate_series(1, 10) 
    GROUP  by 1 
    LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to remove duplicates, start with all distinct numbers from 1 to 10, then select randomly from the list:

```
select generate_series(1,10)
order by random()
limit 5
```

It's basically a cleaner version of Mureinik's answer.